# Nautilus crashes when accessing some folders

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, gnome, directory

Since the past few days, Nautilus has started crashing whenever I access one of the Documents, video, pictures, download folder. It does not happen when I access the home folder and other mounted drives.

The interesting thing is I do not get any error messages, Nautilus simply closes when trying to access these folders.

Can you please tell what might be the problem and how to rectify ?

I have recently installed Gnome-documents and Sushi, and am on Gnome 3.2 with Oneric 11.10.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Empty Template folder solved the problem for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove nautilus config files:

```
rm -rf ~/.nautilus
```

If its not working open nautilus on console, re-do it and copy the log for me pls.

Comment: Hi, thnx for the help....When I try to run the command it says - rm: cannot remove `/home/jigar/.nautilus': No such file or directory

Comment: @Jigar - when replying with additional information please reedit your question to add the additional information.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Try this: rm -rf ~/.nautilus

Comment: Sorry bout that...will do...

Answer (score 9):

Removing nautilus-open-terminal fixed it for me. None of the Ubuntu One client stuff above helped for me, but removing nautilus-open-terminal definitely did. Nautilus now opens, and it seems to open slightly quicker.

With nautilus-open-terminal installed, if I launched nautilus from terminal, I would get a number of segmentation faults, and nautilus would either not open, or it would open then close after browsing a few folders.

After reading a comment in that forum BruceBerry mentioned above, about removing nautilus-open-terminal, the terminal now can just open nautilus with absolutely no error messages and I have Ubuntu One file syncing just fine.

Comment: This. Trying to delete .nautilus didn't help me at all, since there was no such file in my home directory to begin with. Removing nautilus-open-terminal did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

what i did was;

```
sudo apt-get purge nautilus-open-terminal
```

and now everything is just fine!
I love the new distro!

Answer (score 1):

I have this bug too. Apparently a fix will be released soon:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client-gnome/stable-2-0/+bug/865567

Comment: as a workaround, disable ubuntu one file sync

Comment: yeah. its a good thing i have zeitgiest journal and gnome-docs installed through which i can access all my documents and work stuff...

Comment: You are right, it't that bug. I'm also affected.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, the previously mentioned solution of purging nautilus-open-terminal solved my problem, thanks to Elnetotaca

```
sudo apt-get purge nautilus-open-terminal
```