# Nautilus on Ubuntu 11.10 keeps crashing

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

I noticed that my nautilus keeps crashing when I open a folder

Video: http://www.screenr.com/B20s

If more info is required just let me know how I can get them

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: Indeed, you should report a bug rather than asking here. Please note that since this bug looks to be a crash, it would be a good idea to enable Apport crash reporting and report the bug by producing the problem to trigger Apport, which will automatically attach much more important information from the crash than just running "ubuntu-bug nautilus". See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport#How_to_enable_apport. And remember to also read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs carefully before reporting your bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you have the package "nautilus-open-terminal" installed then remove it using Synaptic or using the command:

   ```
   apt-get --purge remove nautilus-open-terminal
   ```
2. Try to remove nautilus config files using the command:

   ```
   rm -rf ~/.nautilus
   ```
3. Find another solution from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64244/nautilus-crashes-when-accessing-some-folders)