# Nautilus crashing when running gksu nautilus

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nautilus on Ubuntu 11.10 keeps crashing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65443/nautilus-on-ubuntu-11-10-keeps-crashing)

When I run gksu nautilus from the terminal, after entering my password, nautilus opens to the root folder as usual, but then crashes when I try to navigate within the file system and I get this error in terminal:

> (nautilus:7160): DEBUG: Syncdaemon not running, waiting for it to start in NameOwnerChanged

Any Ideas?  I am running a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10 Oeniric Ocelot.

I also receive this error:

> (nautilus:7947): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_get: assertion `GCONF_IS_CLIENT (client)' failed

Comment: I also receive this error: (nautilus:7947): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_get: assertion `GCONF_IS_CLIENT (client)' failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Nautilus crashes, chances are this is because of

1) nautilus-open-terminal package, so remove it:

```
sudo apt-get remove nautilus-open-terminal
```

2) You can try to remove ubuntuone-client-gnome and keep nautilus-open-terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntuone-client-gnome
```

It is a way to speed up nautilus too if you don't need it.

Eventualy try also :

```
gconftool-2 --type bool --set '/apps/ubuntuone/nautilus/show-location' false
```

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-open-terminal/+bug/865115
For more.

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to have worked, although I still get the Syncdaemon error...