# Nautilus keeps force closing

Tags: nautilus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nautilus on Ubuntu 11.10 keeps crashing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65443/nautilus-on-ubuntu-11-10-keeps-crashing)

When opening a folder, nautilus randomly closes.

I am using Ubuntu 64bit unity.

Does anyone know where I can start?

Thanks

Running Nautilus in Terminal, until crash. All icons on desktop go, left click disables too.

```
(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_get: assertion `GCONF_IS_CLIENT (client)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_composite: assertion `dest_y >= 0 && dest_y + dest_height <= dest->height' failed

(nautilus:6042): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_composite: assertion `dest_y >= 0 && dest_y + dest_height <= dest->height' failed

(nautilus:6042): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_get: assertion `GCONF_IS_CLIENT (client)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_composite: assertion `dest_y >= 0 && dest_y + dest_height <= dest->height' failed

(nautilus:6042): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_get: assertion `GCONF_IS_CLIENT (client)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_get: assertion `GCONF_IS_CLIENT (client)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_get: assertion `GCONF_IS_CLIENT (client)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_get: assertion `GCONF_IS_CLIENT (client)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_get: assertion `GCONF_IS_CLIENT (client)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_get: assertion `GCONF_IS_CLIENT (client)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_get: assertion `GCONF_IS_CLIENT (client)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_get: assertion `GCONF_IS_CLIENT (client)' failed

(nautilus:6042): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_get: assertion `GCONF_IS_CLIENT (client)' failed
Segmentation fault



Restarting Nautilus and Unity in Terminal, then crash at end:

pst007x@pst007x-ubuntu64:~$ nautilus -q
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 0.6.8
Initializing nautilus-ideviceinfo extension
Initializing nautilus-open-terminal extension
** (nautilus:5621): DEBUG: Syncdaemon not running, waiting for it to start in NameOwnerChanged
Initializing nautilus-gdu extension

(nautilus:5621): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_action_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_ACTION (action)' failed

(nautilus:5621): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_action_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_ACTION (action)' failed

--- Hash table keys for warning below:
--> Paolino Turone
--> pst007x
--> l2049
--> inode/directory

(nautilus:5621): Eel-WARNING **: "unique eel_ref_str" hash table still has 4 elements at quit time (keys above)

--- Hash table keys for warning below:
--> file:///home/pst007x/Desktop
--> x-nautilus-desktop:///
--> file:///home/pst007x

(nautilus:5621): Eel-WARNING **: "nautilus-directory.c: directories" hash table still has 3 elements at quit time (keys above)
Shutting down nautilus-gdu extension
Shutting down nautilus-open-terminal extension
Shutting down nautilus-ideviceinfo extension
pst007x@pst007x-ubuntu64:~$ unity
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Skipping upgrade com.canonical.unity.unity.01.upgrade
Skipping upgrade com.canonical.unity.unity.02.upgrade
Initializing core options...done
Initializing bailer options...done
Initializing detection options...done
Initializing composite options...done
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing decor options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing place options...done
Initializing grid options...done
Initializing move options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Initializing resize options...done
Initializing snap options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
Initializing wall options...done
Initializing animation options...done
Initializing fade options...done
Initializing session options...done
compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing scale options...done
Initializing workarounds options...done
Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done

Screen geometry changed:
   0x0x1366x768

Initializing unityshell options...done
DEBUG 2011-10-15 19:20:19 glib <unknown>:0 Setting to primary screen rect: x=0 y=0 w=1366 h=768
WARN  2011-10-15 19:20:19 glib <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch view type at /org/ayatana/bamf/window31457286: Method "ViewType" with signature "" on interface "org.ayatana.bamf.view" doesn't exist

WARN  2011-10-15 19:20:19 glib <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch view type at /org/ayatana/bamf/application0x11b6340: Method "ViewType" with signature "" on interface "org.ayatana.bamf.view" doesn't exist

WARN  2011-10-15 19:20:19 glib <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch view type at /org/ayatana/bamf/application0x11b6340: Method "ViewType" with signature "" on interface "org.ayatana.bamf.view" doesn't exist

compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x3e00180!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you shouldprobably file a bug about this.
Setting Update "main_menu_key"
Setting Update "run_key"
Setting Update "flip_left_edge"
Setting Update "launcher_reveal_edge"
Setting Update "launcher_hide_mode"
WARN  2011-10-15 19:20:29 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:255 Cannot call method InfoRequest proxy /com/canonical/unity/lens/applications does not exist
WARN  2011-10-15 19:20:29 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:255 Cannot call method SetActive proxy /com/canonical/unity/lens/applications does not exist
WARN  2011-10-15 19:20:29 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:255 Cannot call method InfoRequest proxy /com/canonical/unity/lens/music does not exist
WARN  2011-10-15 19:20:29 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:255 Cannot call method SetActive proxy /com/canonical/unity/lens/music does not exist
WARN  2011-10-15 19:20:29 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:255 Cannot call method InfoRequest proxy /com/canonical/unity/lens/files does not exist
WARN  2011-10-15 19:20:29 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:255 Cannot call method SetActive proxy /com/canonical/unity/lens/files does not exist
WARN  2011-10-15 19:20:29 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:255 Cannot call method InfoRequest proxy /com/canonical/unity/lens/commands does not exist
WARN  2011-10-15 19:20:29 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:255 Cannot call method SetActive proxy /com/canonical/unity/lens/commands does not exist
WARN  2011-10-15 19:20:30 unity.iconloader IconLoader.cpp:509 Unable to load contents of file:///usr/share/icons/unity-icon-theme/places/svg/category-installed.svg: Error opening file: No such file or directory
WARN  2011-10-15 19:20:30 unity.iconloader IconLoader.cpp:509 Unable to load contents of file:///usr/share/icons/unity-icon-theme/places/svg/category-available.svg: Error opening file: No such file or directory
WARN  2011-10-15 19:20:35 glib <unknown>:0 Unable to fetch children: Method "Children" with signature "" on interface "org.ayatana.bamf.view" doesn't exist


WARN  2011-10-15 19:20:35 glib.glib-gobject <unknown>:0 instance of invalid non-instantiatable type `<invalid>'
```

Comment: can you run it via a terminal and post the messages here? Open a terminal and type `nautilus ~/` and post the output in your question when it randomly closes. More the information, more the chances someone can help you.

Comment: I restarted nautilus and then unity in a terminal, and then opened nautilus, then the crash. A lot of errors appeared:

Comment: can you post all the info by editing your question?

Comment: There's too much to post. How do I show the results?

Comment: Doh! posted sorry...

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in launchpad related to this. The proposed "solution" is to uninstall the package nautilus-open-terminal. No more crashes for me.

Comment: Cool that seems to have sorted it. Ubuntu 11.10 still feels like beta, but some nice features. Many Thanks, appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

Nautilus is working great, as all of its official scripts.
What is breaking nautilus is the package ubuntuone-client-gnome. It is Ubuntu that is breaking nautilus, with a bad design in the code of ubuntuone client.

Comment: Can Ubuntuone client be removed safely?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, be careful of any additional scripts to nautilus in Ubuntu 11.10. It is ashame nautilus used to be really cool, now it is so stripped down.

However, Ubuntu is still the best out there!

Thanks