# nautilus crashes when expanding /Downloads folder

Tags: nautilus

also rooted nautilus crashes at the same point. I have removed profiles of nautilus and all suspect files i have downloaded before. There is no error output in the console also no logs in /var which reffering to the crash. I saw that lot of people have the same issue but  any solution fits to me. Thank you fo help

Comment: http://bugs.launchpad.net/gloobus-preview/+bug/690364

Answer (score 3):

I think i found the answer

In xsession-errors log  i found:

```
ERROR:io-xcf.c:1443:xcf_image_stop_load: code should not be reached.
```

it is gloobus-previewer bug which is cousing the crash. 
Pls look here: [bugs.launchpad.net/gloobus-preview/+bug/690364](http://bugs.launchpad.net/gloobus-preview/+bug/690364). 
So what i did is to install [gnome-xcf-thumbnailer](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-xcf-thumbnailer).

I found also the suspect *.xcf.bz2 file in the /Download folder and removed it...

This is whats working for me.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/64244/13398) might be related to your problem. In particular, [one answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/64944/13398) suggests the following solution:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove nautilus-open-terminal
```

Now, open the folder.

Comment: there is such a file, i have checked already this. thank you

Comment: ok if u dont get any answers here,then i suggest you too reinstall nautilus or install another file manager like thunar or pcmanfm

Comment: oh sorry, it should be: there is no such a file installed.

Comment: well, I can also remove this folder and create new one /Downloads

Comment: sum2000, perhaps you should get more info about the questioner's situation before suggesting to remove random packages.

Comment: perhaps you should check this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/64244/nautilus-crashes-when-accessing-some-folders before commenting

Comment: You didn't link to that question. How was anybody to know about that question? I've edited your answer to incorporate this new information.

Comment: hello hello, I think i found the problem: it is gloobus-previewer bug which is cousing the crash. Pls look here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/gloobus-preview/+bug/690364. So what i did is to install gnome-xcf-thumbnailer. I found also the suspect *.xcf.bz2 file and removed that...Now is all OK.

Comment: The error in xsession-errors was looking like this: ERROR:io-xcf.c:1443:xcf_image_stop_load: code should not be reached.

Comment: @butti: Glad you found your answer. So that everyone knows that this question has been answered, would you mind putting the solution into an answer and accepting it?